# Notifications in android studio

Tags: android, notifications

I have questions about notifications in android studio I want to build an app with two buttons (add notification and the other one is remove notification) when I press add notification a notification is create with two addActions (one is Read it and the other one is Likeit ) if I press first addAction it take me to  ResultActivity.class in my app and if i press the second  addAction it take me to another activity called Main2Activity.class in my class when I implement this code the two addAxtions take me to the same activity what is the wrong of my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

 NotificationManager nmanger;
 static int id=1;

public void buclick(View view) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder nbuild= (NotificationCompat.Builder) new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Danger")
            .setContentText("the raining is comming soon")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.amule);



    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );


     Intent resultIntent_2 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder_2 = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder_2.addParentStack(Main2Activity.class);
    stackBuilder_2.addNextIntent(resultIntent_2);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent_2 =stackBuilder_2.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );





    nbuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    nbuild.addAction(R.drawable.computer,"Read it",resultPendingIntent);
    nbuild.addAction(R.drawable.trashcan_empty,"Link it",resultPendingIntent_2);



    nmanger =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nmanger.notify(id,nbuild.build());
    id++;
}

public void removeclick(View view) {

    nmanger.cancelAll();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does this line `nbuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you missed out a line of code right after `nbuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);`

You are just setting the first Intent but not the second.

Comment: thank you sir i put nbuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent_2); after nbuild.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) and app is worked,